# multiply form values from form array with JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have html form with arrays:

```
     <form method="post" id="formaa" name="form">

    <div id="fields">
    <div id="divas1" class="row">
<a href="#" id="did1" onClick="d(this);"><img src="d.jpg" /></a><a href="#" id="uid1" onClick="u(this);">
<img src="u.jpg" /></a><input type="text" name="ite[]" id="item" /><input type="text" name="q[]" id="quantity" class="quant" size="3" />
<input type="text" name="pr[]" id="price" size="10" class="kaina" onkeyup="update();"/><input type="text" name="sum[]" id="suma" size="10" disabled="disabled"/></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="nw" id="new" value="ADD" onClick="naujas('laukeliai');" /><br />
    Total: <input type="text" name="sumaa[]" id="suma" size="10" disabled="disabled"/>
    </form>
```

Each time I push forms ADD button, inside the `<div id="fields">` is included new div block `<div id=divas(i++)>` I need multiply qp[] and pr[] values and dynamicaly add to sum field, need do multiply price and quantity of each product seperately and get final each product price (not all products total).

first tried to get all values and filter these two, but couldnt figure out...

```
var form = document.getElementsByName('form')[0];
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i < j; i++) {
    var element = inputs[i];
    alert(element.value);
}
```

How to extract from this array only needed values and multiply? Thanks for advices.

Comment: Seconded - much easier with ids. Also, for any serious JS, use jQuery if at all possible. Assuming jQuery present, $("#quant[]").val() * $("#pr[]").val() is all you need, with slight modifications if there are a lot of those.

Comment: Downvoted until author edits to specify more clearly what the question is - or upvotes an answer. Suspect homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to generate the sum of the prices for all the products and quantities you bought, you would first rewrite your HTML as:

```
<form id="example_form">
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" name="item" class="item"></input>
  <input type="text" name="quant" class="quant"></input>
  <input type="text" name="price" class="price"></input>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" name="item" class="item"></input>
  <input type="text" name="quant" class="quant"></input>
  <input type="text" name="price" class="price"></input>
</div>    
<!-- ... many more rows -->
<input type="text" disabled id="sum" name="sum"></input>
</form>
```

Use jQuery to make field access easier. Using JQuery, you would use the following JS:

```
function update() {
  var total = 0;
  $("#example_form div.row").each(function(i,o){
    total += $(o).find(".quant").val() *
        $(o).find(".price").val();
  });
  $("#example_form #sum").val(total);
}
```

This will update totals for you. To do this each time any number is changed, you would need to register it with the corresponding fields, using something like

```
$("#example_form div.row input").change(update);
```

Have I convinced you of using JQuery? See it working at [http://jsfiddle.net/UnYJ3/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/UnYJ3/1/)

Comment: Using JQuery is OK, but My form is dynamic and I can add new row of these fields, so it has to be array

Comment: but I need for loop to get all values, because with your code I;m getting 0

Comment: Now its working but instead of values I;m getting NaN instead of number

Comment: I already did that befre.. first value I'm getting corect number, then add new row then I enter new data both sum fields become NaN... I add this function on keyup in price field

Comment: click on the JSFiddle link in the answer, modify it if you need to, save it, and comment again with a better description of your problem. It works for me 100%. Also, if the answer is useful, you should upvote it (click on the 'up' arrow next to the title). If it is complete, click on the checkmark.

Comment: I have tried on JSFiddle this code and its not working correctly. Added 3 divs `<div id="d1 / d2 / d3" class="row">` when I enter values to first row all 3 #sum divs updating together, like summing all values, but not  individualy rows

Comment: there should only be 1 element with a given ID. You should have specified that you needed 1 sum per row, instead of a global sum. Also, this is not a "do my homework" site - ask a question, get an answer. Bad question, bad answer. No more help from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can read form array in way as below

frmRefer = document.getElementByTagName("form")[0];
for(i= 0 ; i<frmRefer.elements["ite[]"].length;i++){
    alert(frmRefer.elements["ite[]"][i].value );
}
for(i= 0 ; i<frmRefer.elements["quant[]"].length;i++){
    alert(frmRefer.elements["quant[]"][i].value );
}
for(i= 0 ; i<frmRefer.elements["pr[]"].length;i++){
    alert(frmRefer.elements["pr[]"][i].value );
}
```